# Kinect for Windows (v1) with SDK 2.0

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I have issues installing Kinect for Windows (the V1 version) using the SDK 2.0. I'm assuming the SDK 2.0  also include drivers necessary for v1 since the download details says *introduces support for the Kinect for Windows v2 sensor*.

The issue I'm having is after plugging the kinect in the USB 3.0 port (the kinect is already plugged to the AC), it install the driver, but the device manager has the yellow triangle, and it keeps making the plugged/unplugged sounds.

Am I missing an step or should I use a different SDK version (if yes, which one)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The kinect SDK 2.0 doesn't work with kinect for Windows v1. What you need are:

- Kinect for Windows SDK v1.8: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40278
- Kinect for Windows Developer Toolkit: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=323589